# in datapower response rule not getting data from backend even backend is working properly

Tags: ibm-datapower

getting result while debugging in response rule

```
   <env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <env:Body>
      <env:Fault>
         <faultcode>env:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Internal Error</faultstring>
      </env:Fault>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope
```

> 

I configure one response rule including match action, transformation action and result action
after hitting request to backend, backend showing valid response in debugger but response rule not picking up this backend response..

whats a solution for this one ?

Answer (score 0):

DataPower response rules may not pick the response in several scenarios:
Incorrect Rule Configuration: If the response rule is not correctly configured or if it does not match the specific criteria set in the rule conditions, it might fail to pick the response.
Rule Priority: If multiple response rules are defined and a rule with higher priority matches the conditions before the desired rule, it can override or bypass the intended response rule.
Processing Errors: DataPower might encounter errors during processing that prevent the evaluation or execution of response rules.